# Proof of $H^k(X,\mathbf k) = H^k(X,\mathbb Z) \otimes \mathbf k$

Tags: manifolds, homology-cohomology

Let $X$ be a compact manifold and denote $H^k(X,G)$ the $k$-th cohomology group with coefficients in the abelian group $G$.

Using Cech cohomology one can prove that there is a natural isomorphism $ H^k(X,\mathbf  k) \simeq H^k(X,\mathbb Z) \otimes \mathbf  k$  for every field $\mathbf k$ of characteristic $0$ (see for instance the book "Hodge Theory and Complex Algebraic Geometry I", C.Voisin p 157.)

Is there a way to proove this fact without using sheaf-cohomology? I have looked around for a "Universal Coefficient Theorem" for cohomology but the only one I know relates $H^k(X,\mathbf k)$ with $H_k(X,\mathbb Z)$ and $H_{k-1}(X,\mathbb Z)$, but not with $ H^k(X,\mathbb Z) $.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If $S_{\bullet}$ is the singular chain complex for $X$, then
$H^i(X,A)$ is computed by the cochain complex $Hom(S_{\bullet},A)$.  Now there is natural map $Hom(S_{\bullet},\mathbb Z) \otimes k \to Hom(S_{\bullet},k),$
 and hence, passing to cohomology, a map 
$$H^{\bullet}(X,\mathbb Z)\otimes k \to
H^{\bullet}(X,k).$$
This will not be an isomorphism for arbitrary spaces $X$.  (E.g. if $X$
is just a disjoint union of a set $I$ of points, then this is the natural
map $(\mathbb Z^I)\otimes k \to k^I$, which is not an isomorphism in general if $I$ 
is infinite.)

However, if the homology groups of $X$ with $\mathbb Z$-coefficients are finitely generated,
then this *will* be an isomorphism, as follows from the [universal coefficient theorem for cohomology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_coefficient_theorem#Universal_coefficient_theorem_for_cohomology) that you mentioned in your question.  (Use the fact
that the universal coefficient short exact sequence is natural in $A$; that $Ext(H_{i-1},A)$ is torsion when $A = \mathbb Z$ --- since $H_{i-1}$ is f.g. by assumption --- and vanishes when $A = k$, since $k$ is of char. zero; and that $Hom(H_i,\mathbb Z)\otimes k \cong Hom(H_i,k)$, since $H_i$ is f.g.)

For a compact manifold the homology groups are f.g., and so the result follows.